# How to stop react-query from sending search request when search string is empty?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, react-query

I use Tanstack React Query to fetch a list of cities based on what is typed in input box(search functionality for an weather app) in a react 18 + typescript app. I use debounced state and set the initial value to empty string. but react-query sends the request with empty string which cause multiple unsuccessful requests with error 400 (shown in browser console) and you can't put hooks in if statements so what should I do?

**I want to send request if the search term (debounced state) length is more than 2 characters.**

### Search Box component:

```js
import { TextInput } from "@mantine/core";
import { useDebouncedState } from "@mantine/hooks";

import useSearch from "../hooks/useSearch";


const SearchBox = () => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useDebouncedState("", 400);
  const { data: suggestedCities, isError, isLoading } = useSearch(searchTerm);

  if (isLoading) <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  if (isError) <h1>Failed to fetch cities list!</h1>;

  return (
    <div>
      <TextInput
        defaultValue={searchTerm}
        onChange={(event) => setSearchTerm(event.currentTarget.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

### useSearch custom hook to fetch data:

```js
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import axios from "axios";

const fetchCitiesList = async (searchTerm: string) => {
  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://weatherapi-com.p.rapidapi.com/search.json",
    params: { q: searchTerm },
    headers: {
      "X-RapidAPI-Key": import.meta.env.VITE_WEATHER_API_KEY,
      "X-RapidAPI-Host": import.meta.env.VITE_WEATHER_API_HOST,
    },
  };

  const { data } = await axios.request(options);
  return data as City[];
};

const useSearch = (searchTerm: string) => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ["search-city", searchTerm],
    queryFn: () => fetchCitiesList(searchTerm),
  });
};

export default useSearch;
```

#### This is what I get in browser console:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use enabled in your query like , which makes the query executes only if the value is true

```
return useQuery({
    enabled: !!searchTerm
    queryKey: ["search-city", searchTerm],
    queryFn: () => fetchCitiesList(searchTerm),
  });
```

https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useQuery

Comment: enabled: searchTerm.length > 1

Comment: yeah if searchTerm is an array this can help

Comment: works with strings too

Comment: !!searchTerm this is fine with string

Comment: yeah, but in question there was a condition - length is more than 2 characters